# libxml2 and libxml2-dev on OSX

Tags: c++, macos

When trying to build the Unix QuickFIX engine, I get the following error after ./bootstrap

```
warning:macro 'AM_PATH_XML2' not found in library
```

As I understand, libxml2 already comes with XCode OS X Mountain Lion.  An answer I found suggested to download libxml2-dev, although I could not find the package using HomeBrew.
I'm relatively new to programming on OS X and Xcode and porting Unix applications, so I'm not sure exactly what I have yet.

Comment: XML definitely isn't a requirement for FIX messages. Unless your counter-party isn't using FIX 4.2, you should be able to ignore this warning.

Answer (score 11):

I did a

```
brew install libxml2
```

Then poking around I found the macro `AM_PATH_XML2` in `/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/share/aclocal/libxml.m4`. Which is all the dev package contents, then I compared to my Ubuntu/Vagrant virtual I have locally that was working fine and remembered to:

```
brew link --force libxml2
```

which put the symlink in `/usr/local/share/aclocal`.

And now I'm building, but I also needed automaker, so to recap

```
brew install automake autoconf libtool libxml2                                                            
brew link libxml2
```

Answer (score 3):

That warning comes from Autoconf and is complaining that the `configure.in` file refers to the macro `AM_PATH_XML2` but it isn't defined.  It should be defined in the file `aclocal.m4` in the quickfix source, so it seems your version of autoconf isn't finding it.
You could try modifying `bootstrap` to run `autoconf -I .`

Comment: I assume you would add the `-I<path/to/aclocal-dir-with-libxml.m4` to `aclocal`?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem trying to build [oath-toolkit](https://gitlab.com/oath-toolkit/oath-toolkit) on my mac. I was able to get past this error by creating a symlink for `libxml.m4` after installing with `brew install libxml2`.

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/libxml2/share/aclocal/libxml.m4 /usr/local/share/aclocal/libxml.m4
```

I realize this question was asked more than 7 years old, but it took me a while to piece together this solution. I hope it helps. I was able to reproduce the problem my running `aclocal`. It errored with `configure.ac:38: warning: macro 'AM_PATH_XML2' not found in library`. I then ran `aclocal --print-ac-dir` which returned `/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.16.1_1/share/aclocal`. That directory contained a `dirlist` file.

```
cat /usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.16.1_1/share/aclocal/dirlist 
/usr/local/share/aclocal
/usr/share/aclocal
```

The first directory contained all of the other symlinks.

```
ls -al /usr/local/share/aclocal
lrwxr-xr-x   1 cameron  admin   48 Sep 20 08:39 cmake.m4 -> ../../Cellar/cmake/3.15.3/share/aclocal/cmake.m4
lrwxr-xr-x   1 cameron  admin   52 Sep 20 09:01 dirlist -> ../../Cellar/automake/1.16.1_1/share/aclocal/dirlist
lrwxr-xr-x   1 cameron  admin   53 Sep 20 09:02 libtool.m4 -> ../../Cellar/libtool/2.4.6_1/share/aclocal/libtool.m4
lrwxr-xr-x   1 cameron  admin   52 Sep 20 09:02 ltargz.m4 -> ../../Cellar/libtool/2.4.6_1/share/aclocal/ltargz.m4
lrwxr-xr-x   1 cameron  admin   50 Sep 20 09:02 ltdl.m4 -> ../../Cellar/libtool/2.4.6_1/share/aclocal/ltdl.m4
lrwxr-xr-x   1 cameron  admin   55 Sep 20 09:02 ltoptions.m4 -> ../../Cellar/libtool/2.4.6_1/share/aclocal/ltoptions.m4
lrwxr-xr-x   1 cameron  admin   53 Sep 20 09:02 ltsugar.m4 -> ../../Cellar/libtool/2.4.6_1/share/aclocal/ltsugar.m4
lrwxr-xr-x   1 cameron  admin   55 Sep 20 09:02 ltversion.m4 -> ../../Cellar/libtool/2.4.6_1/share/aclocal/ltversion.m4
lrwxr-xr-x   1 cameron  admin   57 Sep 20 09:02 lt~obsolete.m4 -> ../../Cellar/libtool/2.4.6_1/share/aclocal/lt~obsolete.m4
lrwxr-xr-x   1 cameron  admin   51 Aug 27 20:15 pkg.m4 -> ../../Cellar/pkg-config/0.29.2/share/aclocal/pkg.m4
```

Following that pattern, I could have done:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2/share/aclocal/libxml.m4 /usr/local/share/aclocal/libxml.m4
```

But I chose to use this symlink so that this answer works with various versions.

```
ls -al /usr/local/opt/libxml2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 cameron  admin  25 Sep 20 09:35 /usr/local/opt/libxml2 -> ../Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2
```