# cpan can't install XML::LibXML on macOS Catalina

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I'm using `cpan install XML::LibXML` to try to install `XML::LibXML` parser, but it won't pass. It gives the following errors:

```
cc -c   -I/usr/include/libxml2  -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3   -DVERSION=\"2.0201\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.0201\"  "-I/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -DHAVE_UTF8 Devel.c
In file included from Devel.xs:28:
/usr/local/include/libxml/xmlmemory.h:16:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h'
  file not found
#include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Devel.o] Error 1
SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0201.tar.gz
/usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
```

**Update:**
After I manually copy the 'dev' files to `/usr/local/include/libxml`,the `file not found` error is gone now, but it still failed to compile `XML-LibXML`.

This is the output information:
[image: output info]

More detailed information:

```
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/Users/chris/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Fri, 05 Jul 2019 03:56:00 GMT
Running install for module 'XML::LibXML'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.01)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.074)
Checksum for /Users/chris/.cpan/sources/authors/id/S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0201.tar.gz ok
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v1.29)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20181129_28)
Configuring S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0201.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for XML::LibXML
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0201.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0201.tar.gz
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Attr.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Attr.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Literal.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Literal.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Namespace.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Namespace.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/RegExp.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/RegExp.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Text.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Text.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Boolean.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Boolean.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/RelaxNG.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/RelaxNG.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/ErrNo.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/ErrNo.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Pattern.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Pattern.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/PI.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/PI.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/XPathContext.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/XPathContext.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/SAX.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/SAX.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/InputCallback.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/InputCallback.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/AttributeHash.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/AttributeHash.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/SAX/Generator.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/SAX/Generator.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Error.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Error.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/SAX.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/SAX.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Reader.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Reader.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/XPathContext.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/XPathContext.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Element.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Element.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/SAX/Builder.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/SAX/Builder.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/XPathExpression.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/XPathExpression.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Common.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Common.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/SAX/Builder.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/SAX/Builder.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Dtd.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Dtd.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/ErrNo.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/ErrNo.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/NodeList.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/NodeList.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/SAX/Parser.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/SAX/Parser.pm
cp LibXML.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Comment.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Comment.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/DOM.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/DOM.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/CDATASection.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/CDATASection.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod
cp LibXML.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Reader.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Reader.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Error.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Error.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/DocumentFragment.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/DocumentFragment.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Common.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Common.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Schema.pod blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Schema.pod
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Number.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Number.pm
cp lib/XML/LibXML/Devel.pm blib/lib/XML/LibXML/Devel.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for LibXML ()
chmod 644 "LibXML.bs"
"/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- LibXML.bs blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.bs 644
cc -c   -I/usr/include/libxml2  -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3   -DVERSION=\"2.0201\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.0201\"  "-I/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -DHAVE_UTF8 Av_CharPtrPtr.c
"/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl" "/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/ExtUtils/typemap' -typemap '/Users/chris/.cpan/build/XML-LibXML-2.0201-28/typemap'  Devel.xs > Devel.xsc
mv Devel.xsc Devel.c
cc -c   -I/usr/include/libxml2  -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3   -DVERSION=\"2.0201\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.0201\"  "-I/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -DHAVE_UTF8 Devel.c
"/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl" "/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/ExtUtils/typemap' -typemap '/Users/chris/.cpan/build/XML-LibXML-2.0201-28/typemap'  LibXML.xs > LibXML.xsc
mv LibXML.xsc LibXML.c
cc -c   -I/usr/include/libxml2  -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3   -DVERSION=\"2.0201\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.0201\"  "-I/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -DHAVE_UTF8 LibXML.c
cc -c   -I/usr/include/libxml2  -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3   -DVERSION=\"2.0201\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.0201\"  "-I/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -DHAVE_UTF8 dom.c
cc -c   -I/usr/include/libxml2  -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3   -DVERSION=\"2.0201\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.0201\"  "-I/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -DHAVE_UTF8 perl-libxml-mm.c
perl-libxml-mm.c:142:18: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void (void
      *, void *, xmlChar *)' (aka 'void (void *, void *, unsigned char *)') to
      parameter of type 'xmlHashScanner' (aka 'void (*)(void *, void *, const
      unsigned char *)') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                xmlHashScan(r, PmmRegistryDumpHashScanner, NULL);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/libxml/hash.h:213:22: note: passing argument to parameter 'f'
      here
                                         xmlHashScanner f,
                                                        ^
perl-libxml-mm.c:234:44: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void
      (void *, xmlChar *)' (aka 'void (void *, unsigned char *)') to parameter
      of type 'xmlHashDeallocator' (aka 'void (*)(void *, const unsigned char
      *)') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        if( xmlHashRemoveEntry(PmmREGISTRY, name, PmmRegistryHashDeallocator) )
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/libxml/hash.h:160:47: note: passing argument to parameter 'f'
      here
                           xmlHashDeallocator f);
                                              ^
perl-libxml-mm.c:301:38: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void
      *(void *, xmlChar *)' (aka 'void *(void *, unsigned char *)') to parameter
      of type 'xmlHashCopier' (aka 'void *(*)(void *, const unsigned char *)')
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        reg_copy = xmlHashCopy(PmmREGISTRY, PmmRegistryHashCopier);
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/libxml/hash.h:208:21: note: passing argument to parameter 'f'
      here
                                         xmlHashCopier f);
                                                       ^
3 warnings generated.
cc -c   -I/usr/include/libxml2  -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3   -DVERSION=\"2.0201\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.0201\"  "-I/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -DHAVE_UTF8 perl-libxml-sax.c
cc -c   -I/usr/include/libxml2  -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3   -DVERSION=\"2.0201\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.0201\"  "-I/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -DHAVE_UTF8 xpath.c
rm -f blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.bundle
LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/lib" cc  -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector-strong  Av_CharPtrPtr.o Devel.o LibXML.o dom.o perl-libxml-mm.o perl-libxml-sax.o xpath.o  -o blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.bundle  \
       -lxml2   \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.bundle
Manifying 34 pod documents
  SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0201.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
The current configuration of allow_installing_outdated_dists is 'ask/yes', but for this option we would need 'CPAN::DistnameInfo' installed. Please install 'CPAN::DistnameInfo' as soon as possible. As long as we are not equipped with 'CPAN::DistnameInfo' this option does not take effect
Running make test for SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0201.tar.gz
"/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- LibXML.bs blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.bs 644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00-report-prereqs.t .............................. # 
# Versions for all modules listed in MYMETA.json (including optional ones):
# 
# === Configure Requires ===
# 
#     Module              Want     Have
#     ------------------- ---- --------
#     Alien::Libxml2       any     0.09
#     Config               any 5.028001
#     ExtUtils::MakeMaker  any     7.34
# 
# === Build Requires ===
# 
#     Module              Want Have
#     ------------------- ---- ----
#     ExtUtils::MakeMaker  any 7.34
# 
# === Test Requires ===
# 
#     Module       Want     Have
#     ------------ ---- --------
#     Config        any 5.028001
#     Errno         any     1.29
#     IO::File      any     1.39
#     IO::Handle    any     1.39
#     POSIX         any     1.84
#     Scalar::Util  any     1.50
#     Test::More    any 1.302164
#     locale        any     1.09
#     utf8          any     1.21
# 
# === Runtime Requires ===
# 
#     Module                    Want  Have
#     ------------------------- ---- -----
#     Carp                       any  1.50
#     DynaLoader                 any  1.45
#     Encode                     any  2.97
#     Exporter                  5.57  5.73
#     IO::Handle                 any  1.39
#     Scalar::Util               any  1.50
#     Tie::Hash                  any  1.05
#     XML::NamespaceSupport     1.07  1.12
#     XML::SAX                  0.11  1.02
#     XML::SAX::Base             any  1.09
#     XML::SAX::DocumentLocator  any undef
#     XML::SAX::Exception        any  1.09
#     base                       any  2.27
#     constant                   any  1.33
#     overload                   any  1.30
#     parent                     any 0.236
#     strict                     any  1.11
#     vars                       any  1.04
#     warnings                   any  1.42
# 
t/00-report-prereqs.t .............................. ok   
t/01basic.t ........................................ Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/01basic.t ........................................ 1/3 
#   Failed test 'LIBXML__VERSION == LIBXML_RUNTIME_VERSION'
#   at t/01basic.t line 18.
#          got: '20909'
#     expected: '20904'
# DO NOT REPORT THIS FAILURE: Your setup of library paths is incorrect!
# 
# 
# Compiled against libxml2 version: 20909
# Running libxml2 version:          20904
# 
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 3.
t/01basic.t ........................................ Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/3 subtests 
t/02parse.t ........................................ Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/02parse.t ........................................ ok       
t/03doc.t .......................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/03doc.t .......................................... ok       
t/04node.t ......................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/04node.t ......................................... ok       
t/05text.t ......................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/05text.t ......................................... ok     
t/06elements.t ..................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/06elements.t ..................................... ok       
t/07dtd.t .......................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/07dtd.t .......................................... ok     
t/08findnodes.t .................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/08findnodes.t .................................... ok     
t/09xpath.t ........................................ Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/09xpath.t ........................................ ok     
t/10ns.t ........................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/10ns.t ........................................... ok       
t/11memory.t ....................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/11memory.t ....................................... skipped: These tests are for authors only!
t/12html.t ......................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/12html.t ......................................... ok     
t/13dtd.t .......................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/13dtd.t .......................................... ok     
t/14sax.t .......................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/14sax.t .......................................... ok     
t/15nodelist.t ..................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/15nodelist.t ..................................... ok     
t/16docnodes.t ..................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/16docnodes.t ..................................... ok     
t/17callbacks.t .................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/17callbacks.t .................................... ok     
t/18docfree.t ...................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/18docfree.t ...................................... ok   
t/19die_on_invalid_utf8_rt_58848.t ................. Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/19die_on_invalid_utf8_rt_58848.t ................. ok   
t/19encoding.t ..................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/19encoding.t ..................................... ok   
t/20extras.t ....................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/20extras.t ....................................... ok     
t/21catalog.t ...................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/21catalog.t ...................................... ok   
t/23rawfunctions.t ................................. Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/23rawfunctions.t ................................. ok   
t/24c14n.t ......................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/24c14n.t ......................................... ok     
t/25relaxng.t ...................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/25relaxng.t ...................................... ok     
t/26schema.t ....................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/26schema.t ....................................... ok   
t/27new_callbacks_simple.t ......................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/27new_callbacks_simple.t ......................... ok     
t/28new_callbacks_multiple.t ....................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/28new_callbacks_multiple.t ....................... ok     
t/29id.t ........................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/29id.t ........................................... ok     
t/30keep_blanks.t .................................. Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/30keep_blanks.t .................................. ok   
t/30xpathcontext.t ................................. Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/30xpathcontext.t ................................. ok     
t/31xpc_functions.t ................................ Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/31xpc_functions.t ................................ ok     
t/32xpc_variables.t ................................ Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/32xpc_variables.t ................................ ok     
t/35huge_mode.t .................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/35huge_mode.t .................................... ok   
t/40reader.t ....................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/40reader.t ....................................... ok       
t/40reader_mem_error.t ............................. Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/40reader_mem_error.t ............................. ok   
t/41xinclude.t ..................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/41xinclude.t ..................................... ok   
t/42common.t ....................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/42common.t ....................................... ok     
t/43options.t ...................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/43options.t ...................................... ok       
t/44extent.t ....................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/44extent.t ....................................... ok   
t/45regex.t ........................................ Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/45regex.t ........................................ ok     
t/46err_column.t ................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/46err_column.t ................................... ok   
t/47load_xml_callbacks.t ........................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/47load_xml_callbacks.t ........................... ok   
t/48_memleak_rt_83744.t ............................ skipped: Test::LeakTrace is required for memory leak tests.
t/48_reader_undef_warning_on_empty_str_rt106830.t .. Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/48_reader_undef_warning_on_empty_str_rt106830.t .. ok   
t/48_removeChild_crashes_rt_80395.t ................ Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/48_removeChild_crashes_rt_80395.t ................ ok   
t/48_replaceNode_DTD_nodes_rT_80521.t .............. Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/48_replaceNode_DTD_nodes_rT_80521.t .............. ok   
t/48_RH5_double_free_rt83779.t ..................... skipped: Test::LeakTrace is required.
t/48_rt123379_setNamespace.t ....................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/48_rt123379_setNamespace.t ....................... ok   
t/48_rt55000.t ..................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/48_rt55000.t ..................................... ok   
t/48_rt93429_recover_2_in_html_parsing.t ........... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/48_rt93429_recover_2_in_html_parsing.t ........... ok   
t/48_SAX_Builder_rt_91433.t ........................ Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/48_SAX_Builder_rt_91433.t ........................ ok   
t/48importing_nodes_IDs_rt_69520.t ................. Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/48importing_nodes_IDs_rt_69520.t ................. ok   
t/49_load_html.t ................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/49_load_html.t ................................... ok   
t/49callbacks_returning_undef.t .................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/49callbacks_returning_undef.t .................... skipped: URI::file is not available.
t/49global_extent.t ................................ Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/49global_extent.t ................................ ok   
t/50devel.t ........................................ Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/50devel.t ........................................ ok     
t/51_parse_html_string_rt87089.t ................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/51_parse_html_string_rt87089.t ................... ok   
t/60error_prev_chain.t ............................. Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/60error_prev_chain.t ............................. ok   
t/60struct_error.t ................................. Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/60struct_error.t ................................. ok   
t/61error.t ........................................ Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/61error.t ........................................ ok   
t/62overload.t ..................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/62overload.t ..................................... ok     
t/71overloads.t .................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/71overloads.t .................................... ok     
t/72destruction.t .................................. Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/72destruction.t .................................. ok   
t/80registryleak.t ................................. Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/80registryleak.t ................................. ok   
t/90shared_clone_failed_rt_91800.t ................. skipped: optional (set THREAD_TEST=1 to run these tests)
t/90stack.t ........................................ Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/90stack.t ........................................ ok   
t/90threads.t ...................................... skipped: optional (set THREAD_TEST=1 to run these tests)
t/91unique_key.t ................................... Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904
t/91unique_key.t ................................... ok     
t/cpan-changes.t ................................... skipped: These tests are for authors only!
t/pod-files-presence.t ............................. ok   
t/pod.t ............................................ skipped: These tests are for authors only!
t/release-kwalitee.t ............................... skipped: These tests are for authors only!
t/style-trailing-space.t ........................... skipped: These tests are for authors only!

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/01basic.t                                      (Wstat: 256 Tests: 3 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  3
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=75, Tests=2528, 16 wallclock secs ( 0.46 usr  0.22 sys +  9.89 cusr  2.32 csys = 12.89 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/75 test programs. 1/2528 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0201.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0201.tar.gz`
```

Comment: See also [libxml2 and libxml2-dev on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11706007/2173773)

Comment: By the way, `cpan install XML::LibXML` should be `cpan XML::LibXML`. Your command tries two install two modules (install and XML::LibXML)

Comment: The "dev" files (the .h and library files) for libxml2 are needed to install XML::LibXML

Comment: How should I specify where to find those dev files for libxml2? I just updated the libxml2, so I know where the latest are, but don't know where to update the settings.

Comment: The error message from the `cpan` installer: `... XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20909, but runtime libxml2 is older 20904` you seem to have two different version libxml2.. Try to figure out where they are located and remove the older one

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have two version libxml2. So I figured it out finally… and get it working.

Answer (score 9):

So after many trials and errors, I finally solved this in two simple steps:

1.Copy all the `.h` files in `/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2/libxml` to `/usr/local/include/libxml`

2.Copy the files and folder in `/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib` to `/usr/local/lib` respectively.

And that solves the problem.
:)

Thanks, @Håkon Hægland and @ikegami for pointing the right direction.